# How to filter from a list based on multiple wildcards in python without using a loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following list I want to filter to get everything that starts with peter and steve. I eventually want to add more conditions as well. How can I filter this list given a set of patterns without looping through the entire list? I have something with fnmatch but i can only get it for one pattern adn I don't want to loop. Is there a more pythonic way of doing this?

```
12 = ['peter_1', 'peter_2', 'peter_3', 'jerry', 'tim', 'johnson', 'steve_1', 'steve_2']
pattern = 'peter*'

fnmatch.filter(l2, pattern)
```

Comment: Why `pandas` tag?

Answer (score 0):

Pandas offers a way to do vectorized string operations.

```
names = ['peter_1', 'peter_2', 'peter_3', 'jerry', 'tim', 'johnson', 'steve_1', 'steve_2']
patterns = ['peter', 'steve']

names = pd.Series(names)

satisfies = pd.Series([False]*len(names))

for pat in patterns:
    satisfies = satisfies | names.str.startswith(pat)
    
print(names.loc[satisfies])
```

Comment: this is a loop, i was asking for a pythonic solution if possible

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably need to loop once for any solution to this problem. But it feels like a good fit for regex, especially if you're planning to add more conditions.

```py
import re

names = ['peter_1', 'peter_2', 'peter_3', 'jerry', 'tim', 'johnson', 'steve_1', 'steve_2']
pattern = '^(peter|steve)'
matches = [n for n in names if re.search(pattern, n)]
print(matches)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

```
import re

lst = ['peter_1', 'peter_2', 'peter_3', 'jerry', 'tim', 'johnson', 'steve_1', 'steve_2']
pattern = r'^(peter|steve)'

filtered_lst = list(filter(lambda x: re.search(pattern, x), lst))
```

Output:

```
>>> filtered_lst
['peter_1', 'peter_2', 'peter_3', 'steve_1', 'steve_2']
```

If you use `pandas`, use [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
sr = pd.Series(names)
pattern = r'^(?:peter|steve)'

filtered_sr = sr[sr.str.contains(pattern)]
```

Output:

```
>>> filtered_sr
0    peter_1
1    peter_2
2    peter_3
6    steve_1
7    steve_2
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, based on `numpy` (`l` is the list):

```
np.array(l)[np.char.startswith(l,'peter') | np.char.startswith(l,'steve')].tolist()
```

Output:

```
['peter_1', 'peter_2', 'peter_3', 'steve_1', 'steve_2']
```